# $ not defined Rails 5.1.4, defined on random refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

This is to the point that i have no other ideas. On refresh 2/3 times, jQuery will work and then not.

I've tried rearranging my =require statments in my `application.js` is every way i thought possible.

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require js.cookie
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require selectize
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Development environment has no problems, but Production running Rails 5.1.4 with Passenger Standalone with Turbolinks 5. Just will not work.

I tried moving all `$(function()` or `$(document).` references to this below and yet the issue persists.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
....
}
```

I do have some code that are loaded in .erb files, within  blocks. Maybe this is the issue?

Example:

```
...
<div class="input-field">
  <select id="case_type" name="case_type">
    <option data-key="blank" value="" disabled selected>Choose a type</option>
    <% @categories_and_types.each do |key,types| %>
      <% data_key = key.gsub(/[^\w]/,'_').downcase %>
      <% types.each do |type| %>
        <option value="<%= type %>" data-key="<%= data_key %>"><%= type %></option>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </select>
  <label>Case Type</label>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
      if ($('#case_category').data('options') === undefined) {
        $('#case_category').data('options', $('#case_type option').clone());
      }
</script>

...
```

Do i need to use javascript_tag instead of actual  blocks?

This is how my head looks.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, defer: Rails.env.production? %>
```

Im using `defer` instead of `async` because of suggestions that it would solve this error. Still remains.

So the page loads, the $ not defined shows up, i do the following and its defined.

[image]

This doesnt make any sense. This has gotta be a Turbolinks BUG or something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you expose which code are you put in `.erb`

Comment: added an example

Comment: And some additional insight

Comment: https://gist.github.com/uzaif313/8568f08cef618806114b5f34cd473263

Comment: check above gist

Comment: I will give this a try. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158578/discussion-between-uzaif-and-jaison-brooks).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that your inline `<script>` is being executed *before* the deferred application.js file has loaded. jQuery is compiled in your application.js file (with the `defer` attribute) and therefore won't be available until the document has been parsed.

If possible, I'd recommend putting all of your JavaScript code in your application.js file. You need to be careful to avoid duplicating event listeners with inline scripts and turbolinks. For example, if I were to revisit the page with the example code, it would add another `turbolinks:load` event handler. So either you remove the event listener when leaving the page, or put all your scripts in the application.js file.

Related issue: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/281

---

Aside: it looks like you are missing some closing brackets in your script:

```
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
      if ($('#case_category').data('options') === undefined) {
        $('#case_category').data('options', $('#case_type option').clone());
      }
    });
  </script>
```